# What is the term for a photo of an object from 360 degrees?

Tags: terminology, 360-panorama

I am doing some game development and have a sphere that I want to use as a human head. I need an image to attach to the shape, but I'm not sure what to search for.

When I search for "360 photo" I get something like this which seems to be what I want. When I add it to sphere it looks continuous:

[image]

However when I search "360 head" the best thing I see is stuff like this, which does not work:

[image]

Is there a better term for this than "360 photo"? How can I find images like this of objects, rather than panoramas?

Comment: human head is not spherical :-P and you are going to need much more than just a photo to get realistic effect, see this and related videos to learn what techniques are typically used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZDMFkj8GqA

Comment: @szulat I don't really care about it being realistic, but thanks for the link anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're thinking of is an *object movie*. (See [KR Pano's demonstration of object movies](https://krpano.com/examples/objects/)).

Object movies are how a stitched panorama created from 2D images of an object (typically on a turntable) can be displayed as a virtual object, usually for product purposes.

But I don't think it's going to work the way you imagine to map one onto a sphere. The equirectangular panorama that you found would most typically be used in CGI software as an environment map or skybox, not onto an object.